# Writing C# managed code in native C++

Tags: c#, .net, interop, c++-cli, managed-c++

I am developing a managed lib (using Microsoft Web Services) and I am
including it into a c++ project. The project doesn't use `/clr` option,
so when I include my library's header file VS2005 show me an error
saying I have to use `/clr` option. Doing this I have a incompatibility
with  `/EHs` command line option (error D8016), but changing from `EHs` to
no exception handling not solving problem and keep showing me same error .

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't write C# and C++ code in the same project.

Comment: You cannot create a managed lib without using the `/clr` option.

Comment: @CodyGray : Yes you can; read up on [.netmodule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k669k83h.aspx) files.

Comment: @user765829 : `/EHa` must be used in conjunction with `/clr`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Where does that link say anything about C#?

Comment: @CodyGray : .netmodule files are a concept universal to .NET, not specific to any language, but C#'s documentation for them is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58scf68s.aspx).

Comment: @ildjarn: Uhh, so you're basically trying to tell me that all .NET languages (including C# and C++/CLI) compile down to MSIL code? Yeah, I knew that. It doesn't make my comment any less true. **You cannot write C# and C++ code in the same project.** You can certainly compile C# code to MSIL and then use *that* in a C++/CLI project. But it's not C# code. It's IL code. This is fundamentally no different than using a DLL written in C# from a C++/CLI or even VB.NET application.

Comment: @CodyGray : That's like arguing that statically linking one C++ library to another isn't using "C++ code" because "one isn't C++ code, it's an object file" -- how silly. I'm not sure what point you're so vehemently trying to make, but I was merely pointing out that one may produce _a single resulting assembly_ composed of code written in both C# and C++/CLI, which to most people isn't *semantically* a whole lot different than having C# and C++/CLI code in the same project.

Comment: Not at all. You're twisting a bunch of terminology to arrive at a strange conclusion. This is nothing like static linking in C++. .NET developers approach this very differently. But it's not worth arguing with you, you're not even the person who asked the question. I don't much care if you understand it. To **EVERYONE** it's 100% semantically different. Every .NET developer, that is. We're not talking about implementation details here. We're not talking about how it works under the hood. You could use ILMerge, too. But that's completely irrelevant to my comment.

Comment: @CodyGray : This is **exactly the same** as static linking in C++, but I'll assume other people are capable of actually reading the documentation linked to.

Comment: @ildjarn: Sorry if I seemed angry when replying last night. I was a bit distracted & frustrated. Anyway, I'm indeed aware of what you're talking about, and I agree that you can create assemblies containing IL code generated from any of the .NET-compliant languages. I think the confusion resulted from my use of the word "project". I meant it in the strict sense of what VS terms a project, not in the loose sense of a design project or even the result as a single assembly. You can't have a VS project with C# & C++/CLI code. There are post build workarounds, but I didn't see those as germane here.

Answer (score 4):

If you have unmanaged C++ code and want to use managed code, you have a few options:

- Change your unmanaged code to C++/CLI, by use of the `/clr` switch.
- Write a C++/CLI wrapper library. It could DLL-export unmanaged functions which you call in your unmanaged code.
- Skip the wrapper library and directly DLL-export unmanaged functions via [this library](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/csharpprojecttemplateforunmanagedexports).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a managed lib from an unmanaged c++ application. Since you add the /clr option, your c++ application becomes managed too (just for the record :) )

Here's what might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffkc918h.aspx - the restrictions of the /clr option.

Comment: Almost correct: To use a managed library from unmanaged code, you need to create a wrapper library or otherwise export unmanaged symbols.

Comment: no, its wont work , in that link it tells tat wat are thing clr not compitable , i wann to solve this error , no solution till found on specified link :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write managed c++ adapter, that will call the C# library, and call this adapter from unmanaged c++ program as you would usually call a normal c++ library. You will compile your adapter library with /clr and your main c++ program without /clr if for whatever reason you want to keep it unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a mono environment and start an AppDomain. mono's runtime API will allow you to instantiate classes and call members on them. It will be clumsy, but is will work

http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

Note that Mono is a full .Net 4.0 compliant CLR and it can work with the Microsoft core libraries on Windows.

On windows and Unix it can work with the Mono corlib/class libraries. There are areas not covered in Mono, but they seem to get sparse. You can use the MoMa tool to spot whether your application uses incompatible/incomplete APIs.

Or you can just use the Microsoft .NET framework, assuming you're on windows anyway!